# GoDaddy API is asking for nameservers to create a DNS record

Tags: dns, nameservers, godaddy-api, a-records

I'm using the GoDaddy API to do things like register domains and configure their DNS. [This endpoint](https://developer.godaddy.com/doc/endpoint/domains#/v1/recordReplace) creates a DNS record, and I'm using it to create an `A record`.

```
PUT /v1/domains/{domain}/records
```

Weirdly, it is responding with this error:

```
Status code 422
{
  "code":"MISSING_NAME_SERVER",
  "message":"At least two NS records must be specified in the request body"
}
```

This makes no sense because the schema does not allow nameservers... and an A record doesn't need a nameserver. The domain itself does indeed have nameservers set (set during the registration).

This is what I'm passing to the endpoint to generate the above error:

```
[
    {
    "data": "<my IP address>",
    "name": "",
    "ttl": 3600,
    "type": "A",
    "port":443,
    "priority": 0,
    "protocol": "https",
    "service": "",
    "weight": 0,
    "type": "A"
  }
]
```

Comment: This sounds like a problem better addressed to Godaddy tech support.

Comment: GoDaddy tech support said: "API users are excepted to know how to use REST API calls themselves and be able to troubleshoot them. GoDaddy does not provide guidance on the use of our APIs, we only ensure that the APIs are working on the server end." I am trying to convince them that I am indeed qualified, but hey, maybe I'm wrong and there's something obvious that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote, "PUT /v1/domains/{domain}/records"

The documentation says to use PATCH (not PUT).

I verified that by using PUT I received your error and with PATCH it worked.

Regards, Teacher Todd

Comment: Both are in the documentation. One patches and the other puts.